# I generated the multiple pdf from dompdf but how can I save these files locally

Tags: php, html, dynamic, dompdf

I generated the multiple pdf from dompdf but how can I save these files locally, because these files only open in the web browser. How can I save them into the server?

my code

```
include '../../libs/vendor/autoload.php';
include '../../libs/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';


use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (isset($_FILES['challan']['tmp_name'])) {
        $challan = $_FILES['challan']['tmp_name'];

        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($challan);

        $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();

        if (!empty($sheetData)) {
            
              
        $html = ob_get_clean();
                $html = stripslashes($html);
                
                $html = <<<HTML
                  <html>
                      <head>
                            <style type="text/css">
                                /* Your document styling goes here */
                            </style>
                      </head>
                      <body>
                HTML;
                
                for ($i=0; $i<count($sheetData); $i++) {
                $name = $sheetData[$i][0];
                $fatherName = $sheetData[$i][1];
                $rollNo = $sheetData[$i][2];
                $class = $sheetData[$i][3];
                $dept = $sheetData[$i][4];
                $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
                $html .= '<p>Hello World</p>';
                $dompdf->load_html($html);
                $dompdf->render();
                file_put_contents('pdf', $dompdf->output());
                $dompdf->stream();
                }
      }
    }
}
```

I updated the code again, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method [`output()`](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/src/Dompdf.php#L946) to get the PDF content and save into a file using [`file_get_contents()`](https://php.net/file_get_contents):

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.pdf', $dompdf->output());
```

**EDIT** after question changed :

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($sheetData); $i++) 
{
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);

    $dompdf->render();
    file_put_contents('pdf' . $i . '.pdf', $dompdf->output());
    $dompdf->stream();
}
```

But it seems strange to generate N times, the same PDF.

Comment: yes I am using the output but there is a problem, when I use the output method it's generated only one file instead of a 3,4 file.

Comment: I tried pasting this line of code in the loop but still generating the single file, I updated the code please have a look at it.

Comment: You are generating the same `'pdf'` file. Use something like `'pdf' . $id`.

Comment: Yes, I checked the edited answer but still, it's not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228729/discussion-between-hadiniazi-and-syscall).

Comment: Sorry I haven't enough time to help you for a live debugging or a discussion. I think you should clarify your question.

Comment: my last question, I updated the code again as you said, is there any mistake inside it. Thank you

Comment: `file_put_contents('pdf', $dompdf->output());` should be `file_put_contents('file' . $i . '.pdf', $dompdf->output());`.

Comment: Thank you, man solved my problem, there is a little issue that, the first page is generating exactly what I want but on the second page I am receiving the first page data and the second-page values also.

Comment: The problem might be near `$html = ob_get_clean();`. But I think it should be another question (that have already changed several times). _"solved my problem"_, so, please, don't forget the green check for futur readers (and maybe a vote) :) Thank you.